# Call JS through Actionscript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I'm trying to run Javascript using ActionScript3.

This is the code, binded to a button:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function call_javascript(evt:MouseEvent):void {
ExternalInterface.call("alert", "JS");
}

js_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, call_javascript);
```

This is my HTML:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="js" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="js.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name='AllowScriptAccess' value='always'/>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="js.swf" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="js.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="play" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="window" />
        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
        <param name="menu" value="true" />
        <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
        <param name="salign" value="" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Scarica Adobe Flash Player" />
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

When I press the button nothing happens, why?
I'm using FlashProfessional CS6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [call() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29) takes the js function name and arguments as separate parameters.

Try this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("alert", "JS");
```

**EDIT**: you also need to [allow script access](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c9b.html) in your HTML page.

Add this to your SWF's container HTML page

```
<param name='AllowScriptAccess' value='always'/>
```

For example:

```
<object id='MyMovie.swf' classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' codebase='http://download.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0' height='100%' width='100%'> 
<param name='AllowScriptAccess' value='always'/> 
<param name='src' value=''MyMovie.swf'/> 
<embed name='MyMovie.swf' pluginspage='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer' src='MyMovie.swf' height='100%' width='100%' AllowScriptAccess='never'/> 
</object>
```

**EDIT 2:** Running this locally will only work if the files belong to the local-trusted security sandbox. From the documentation:

> For SWF files running locally, calls to these methods are successful
>   only if the SWF file and the containing web page (if there is one) are
>   in the local-trusted security sandbox. Calls to these methods fail if
>   the content is in the local-with-networking or local-with-filesystem
>   sandbox.

Comment: Have you set `allowScriptAccess` to true in the code? You can verify this with `var isAvailable:Boolean = ExternalInterface.available;`

Comment: Seems not enabled, how can I enable it?

Comment: Are you testing this locally or on a web-server? Local testing might be putting the file in the wrong security sandbox. From the link I posted: `For SWF files running locally, calls to these methods are successful only if the SWF file and the containing web page (if there is one) are in the local-trusted security sandbox. Calls to these methods fail if the content is in the local-with-networking or local-with-filesystem sandbox.`

Comment: Yes that's the problem! I was starting it within FlashPro instead of from my XAMPP server. From XAMPP it works. If you add this to your answer I can mark it as correct.